# Text Decoration Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and when I entered the command to get rid of bullets, using text decoration in my articles, nothing happened. I tried placing in different bits of the code, but still nothing. Any suggestions on what is causing it not to work?

http://codepen.io/alexlwilson/full/kxGwg

UPDATE: THE FIX IS THIS:
     li {
      list-style:none;
     }

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: by text decorations do you just mean the underlines on the links?  Other forms of decoration are other things entirely.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Relevant code? Where do you not want text decorations? Are you just talking about strikethroughs and underlines?

Comment: I'm talking about the bullets, sorry.

Comment: the bullets would be `ul { list-style-type: none; }`

Comment: Please flag this question, for wrong answer its been accepted with the wrong answer and information, which could misguide the people in the community

Comment: @alex_wilson If you plan on using SO in the future you may want to accept an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a general rule for links:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

or

```
article a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your CSS that applies to anchor tags in the article.

This should help:

```
article a:link,
article a:active,
article a:visited,
article a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

For UX clarity I would also recommend:

```
article a:active,
article a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The original question source: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3f6615ef-e3ca-4079-a761-30afd6644a34/view-source

After multiple changes the OP finally mentioned removing bullets from list items not removing text-decorations.

The answer to that *new* question is:

```
li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I placed the above code in wrong, nothing changed: http://codepen.io/alexlwilson/full/kxGwg .

Comment: Thanks for your help, I also used your code, works much better.

Answer (score 0):

what about this simple solution??

```
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}
```